# find the coordinates of the area of the largest isosceles triangle that can be inscribed in an ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, lagrange-multiplier

for the given ellipsoid  $$x^2+ \frac{y^2}{4}=1$$
I have to find the coordinates of  isosceles triangle that can be inscribed in this ellipsoid. the basis of the triangle is parallel to x axis

*My attempt*: 
I am using Lagrange multipliers for solving this question.
using some Geometry , i noticed that , because I want to find the max area, if $(x,y)$ is a given point in the triangle, it should be on the ellipse. 
So, if $(x,y)$ is one of the basis coordinates, then the other coordinate of the basis is $(-x,y)$ cause we want the max area. 
Now,because we looking for isosceles triangle , the last coordinate is $(0,1)$ 
So, we get that the area of triangle is: $$x(1+y)$$
Then, I define $f(x,y)=x(1+y)$ and $g(x,y)=x^2+ \frac{y^2}{4}-1$ 
and for a given $(x,y)$ $x>0$ I can find the area of the triangle. 
So i have the constraint $g(x,y)$ and the function $f$ ,using Lagrange multipliers, I can solve this problem.
My question is: Did I solve this question ? because I feel something isn't working well. Thanks very much!

Comment: The area of the triangle is determined by a single value $x^*$, so cast everything into an equation in a single variable $x$ and optimize.  Whenever you see a $y$, use the equation of the ellipse to substitute $y = 2\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: how i can write y as a function of x?

Comment: The coordinates of the vertices of the triangle are $(x,y),(-x,y)$ and $(0,2).$ Use Pythagoras with the triangle given by $(0,y),(x,y)$ and $(0,2)$ to relate $x$ and $y.$

Comment: Thanks, that what i do for solving this question, i am using lagrange multipliers, so i solve this equations: 
$$f(x,y)=0$$ $$\nabla f= a \nabla g$$ , my question is : if im done everything fine until i want use this equations.  another question, the last coordinate should be $(0,-2)$ so $f(x,y)=x(y+2)$

Answer (score 1):

Affine maps preserve the ratios of areas, hence in order to find the largest inscribed triangles we may just apply $\psi:(x,y)\mapsto (x,2y)$ to an equilateral triangle inscribed in the unit circle. Among these triangles with maximum area there clearly are isosceles triangles, for instance  $\psi(ABC)$ where $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle inscribed in the unit circle and $AB$ is parallel to the $x$- or $y$- axis. The solution is clearly not unique, as well as the maximum area is clearly $\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{3}$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y)=x(1+y)$,

$g(x,y)=x^2+ \frac{y^2}{4}-1$

The point lies on the ellipse thus 
$
0=x^2+ \frac{y^2}{4}-1$
$$y^2=4(1-x^2)$$
$$y=\pm2\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

put this value in $f(x,y)$

$$f(x,y)=x\left(1\pm2\sqrt{(1-x^2)}\right)$$

now can you maximize this?

Comment: thanks,i meant to use Lagrange multipliers, so $f(x,y)=0$ $\nabla f= a\nabla g $
so i can minimize it , using lagrange multipleris, my question was if all the assumption i made until  using this equations is well
another question, the last coordinate should be (0,-2) and not (0,1) right? i think i made a mistake there. so $f(x,y)=x(y+2)$